# Getting "cannot extract an associated type from a higher-ranked trait bound in this context" error in Rust

Tags: rust

When I run this code that uses higher-ranked trait bounds:

```
pub trait MyTrait<'a> {
    type Output: 'a;
    fn gimme_value(&self) -> Self::Output;
}

pub fn meow<T: for<'a> MyTrait<'a> + 'static>(val: &T) -> T::Output {
    val.gimme_value()
}
```

I'm seeing this error:

```
error[E0212]: cannot extract an associated type from a higher-ranked trait bound in this context
```

How can I make my function `meow` return this associated type, while still allowing `T` to be a higher ranked trait bound?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add a new generic to the `meow` function — let's call it `R`. When adding the trait restriction for `T`, define that `T::Output` is equal to `R`. Then, have the function return `R` instead of `T::Output`:

```
pub trait MyTrait<'a> {
    type Output: 'a;
    fn gimme_value(&self) -> Self::Output;
}

pub fn meow<R, T: for<'a> MyTrait<'a, Output=R> + 'static>(val: &T) -> R {
    val.gimme_value()
}
```